# Log with exception data

Tags: python, logging

I need to log fatal in python standard logging module but with exception details.

I can use `log.exception()` but it's an error and not fatal.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging

Comment: `exc_info=True`

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
logger.fatal(msg, exc_info=True)
```

Note that the log level `FATAL` is an (apparently undocumented) alias for the log level `CRITICAL` ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L92)). Accordingly, `Logger.fatal()` is an alias to `Logger.critical()` ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1483)).